Why doesn't control flow analysis narrow union types with optional properties?
I'm trying to understand a TypeScript design decision regarding type narrowing and control flow analysis. Consider the following code:
interface HasOptionalSession {
  session?: string;
}

interface HasSession {
  session: string;
}

function ensureSession(input: HasOptionalSession | HasSession): HasSession {
  if (typeof input.session !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('Session is required');
  }
  return input; // TypeScript error: Type 'HasOptionalSession | HasSession' is not assignable to type 'HasSession'.
}

I expected TypeScript to infer that after the check, input must be of type HasSession. However, it doesn't narrow the type as expected.
In contrast, Python's type checkers (like mypy) can handle this kind of narrowing:
from typing import Union, TypedDict

class HasOptionalSession(TypedDict, total=False):
    session: str

class HasSession(TypedDict):
    session: str

def ensure_session(input: Union[HasOptionalSession, HasSession]) -> HasSession:
    if not isinstance(input.get('session'), str):
        raise ValueError('Session is required')
    return input  # mypy correctly infers this is HasSession

Why doesn't TypeScript narrow the type in this case? Is there a fundamental difference in how TypeScript and Python approach type narrowing, especially with optional properties?
I understand I can use type assertions or user-defined type guards to achieve the desired result in TypeScript:
function assertHasSession(input: HasOptionalSession | HasSession): asserts input is HasSession {
  if (typeof input.session !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('Session is required');
  }
}

function ensureSession(input: HasOptionalSession | HasSession): HasSession {
  assertHasSession(input);
  return input; // This works
}

But I'm curious about the reasoning behind TypeScript's behavior in the original example. Are there specific challenges or trade-offs that prevent TypeScript from narrowing types in this scenario?

If input.session is a string, then input could still be a HasOptionalSession with its .session being set. For narrowing of discriminated unions to work, you need distinct discriminator types.

@Bergi thanks for the clarification. Is it documented anywhere the reason behind it working this way?

The union HasOptionalSession | HasSession is equivalent to HasOptionalSession: every HasSession is a valid HasOptionalSession, because every string is a valid string | undefined. There's no way to filter such a union to just HasSession. Indeed you could just make the function accept HasOptionalSession and nothing changes.

(see prev comment) Essentially the union is a red herring here, and you're really looking for parent narrowing by property narrowing as per ms/TS#42384, which, if implemented, might look like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz yes  ms/TS#42384 is closely aligned with what I'm looking for. I believe you've already posted an answer, happy to close it out unless you were implying that you were going to write a new answer.

I have not posted an answer, just corrected a typo on an existing answer. The other answer is fine although its suggestion is to turn your union into a discriminated union (and it's not clear to me if you want HasOptionalSession to have a hasSession: false), which is different from my suggestion of narrowing an object by property. Let me know how you want to proceed.

This is a quite famous and much requested TypeScript issue you encountered (see microsoft/TypeScript#42384). In general TypeScript does not narrow an object type when you narrow one of its properties unless you are working with discriminated unions.
TypeScript has specific rules for an object's property to be considered discriminant. One of them is that the property must have a literal type. More specifically, at least one of the common property types must have such a literal. string and string | undefined are no literals which is why your narrowing doesn't work.
Here's one possible variant to make this work:
interface HasOptionalSession {
  hasSession: false;
  session?: string; // <- or completely remove this property
                    //    depending on your requirements
}

interface HasSession {
  hasSession: true;
  session: string;
}

function ensureSession(input: HasOptionalSession | HasSession): HasSession {
  if (!input.hasSession) {
    throw new Error("Session is required");
  }

  return input; // compiles
}

TypeScript Playground

string? isn't even a type

Thanks @Bergi! Been writing too much C# recently ;D

GH issue is helpful, thanks. Are there docs that document these rules as well as why they were chosen? Something akin to python's peps

Narrowing occurs when the type is not satisfied For example
let numOrString: string | number = ''
if (typeof numOrString === 'string') {
  numOrString // string
} else {
  numOrString // number
}

But your case string or undefined satisfied for string type.
Change HasOptionalSession to NoSession to get the desired result
interface NoSession {
  session: undefined;
}

interface HasSession {
  session: string;
}

function ensureSession(input: NoSession | HasSession): HasSession {
  if (typeof input.session !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('Session is required');
  }
  return input; // HasSession
}


This does not answer the question. OP clearly states in the question that they understand how to make it work, the question is about why Typescript is the way it is here.

It kind of does answer the question where it says "But your case string or undefined satisfied for string type."... it's just not very clear.
